# When to call PostQuitMessage

Tags: c++, c, winapi, application-close

Like many applications, mine creates multiple windows. I do not know and cannot keep track of how many windows have been created, so I don't know when there are none.

My problem is that when all the windows are closed, unless I call `PostQuitMessage` somehow, the application keeps running with no windows open (obviously). I can't call `PostQuitMessage` in the message handler in response to the `WM_DESTROY` message because that will close all the windows when the first one is closed, even if there are twenty others still open.

My question is how do I know when to call `PostQuitMessage(0)` to actually terminate the application?

Comment: Why can you not keep track of how many windows are open?

Comment: @Gabe because apparently I'm too stupid to see how simple it is to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just keep a static variable with a count of the number of open windows. When a windows opens have it increment the counter; in the WM_DESTROY handler decrement it. When the count goes to zero, call PostQuitMessage.

Comment: Wow, no idea why I didn't think of this. Is that the common way of keeping track of the number of windows in existence?

Comment: @Seth, most applications have a main window even if they have other windows open, so no it's not common.

Comment: Then does the main window have a seperate window procedure? You obviously couldn't have the `PostQuitMessage` in a wndproc that was used by child windows. I'm brand new to win32 GUI programming, pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 5):

If, for some reason, you really can't count how many windows the application opens, you can still use `EnumThreadWindows()` and when there are no more windows, you `PostQuitMessage()`. If you have several threads, make sure you enumerate through those too.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633495%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumThreadWindows(
  __in  DWORD dwThreadId,
  __in  WNDENUMPROC lpfn,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the only clean way is keeping track of your windows and post the quitmessage if none is left.

A possible workaround would be using one of the window enumerating functions. You can count your windows using EnumWindows() which calls a callback where you can count all toplevel windows. If it reaches zero, call PostQuitMessage().

Answer (score 0):

A static variable for the number of the windows?
I have never seen such a Program.
One the one hand child windows can open and close during the lifetime of the
application.
One the other hand the main window procedure has to close the application,
if the user closes the main window.
For to do this, we have to add PostQuitMessage(0) in the WM_DESTROY branch
of the main window procedure. After this message, GetMessage() returns 0 and
the message loop ends because of this (and the application ends too)